# Imperfections when importing 2D PNG based SVG into Blender

Tags: import, image

I used InkScape to create an SVG from a reasonably small PNG of an image. The image was unfortunately slightly pixelated in places which has given me the following in blender.
[image]

The little "notch" in the middle shouldn't be there. The whole point of the exercise is to create a base for generation of pixel perfect renders of this icon at any size (as scaling up a PNG looks terrible.
Can someone suggest a way of correcting the notch to make it more or less straight? Or a way of using this as the base to generate a more perfect shape.

I'm new to Blender but I have basic knowledge for manipulation of meshes.

Comment: I'd probably correct this in inkscape before bringing it into blender (for such a simple shape I might even trace it manually if auto-tracing gives artifacts). That said, if it's fresh from the importer it should be a curve object, in which case you can edit it in blender (in edit mode; press `Tab`) just like you would edit curves in inkscape.

Comment: @gandalf3 is rigth you should fix it Inkscape. However my experience  with Blender and Inkscape that nearly every shape is more easily reproducible in Blender then Inkscape. For me Blender is easier even for 2d images.

Comment: thanks to both. I'll just take the time to figure out how to do it manually in blender.